# Console Error when Starting Blender: SetChannelMap - Is this Normal? What does this mean?

Tags: python, command-line

Here's an image of my console window that pops up right before Blender opens:

[image]

Blender continues to run normally after, but the error still bugs me. And I didn't get the same error on my laptop.

After some google-fu, there was 1-2 posts about it from other users but nobody could really elaborate on what it means or why it's there. An unrelated result pointed to some kind of audio issue. Apparantly AL lib is OpenAL (Open Audio Library).

Full text of the error: AL lib: (EE) SetChannelMap: Failed to match front-center channel (2) in channel map

Do any of you get this as well? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: I've seen some stuff about this too - one discussion regarded something about a conflict/interaction with Windows audio handlers. Other users have reported that this problem was caused by old leftover files from a graphics (drawing) tablet in the system32 folder. Removing these "bad" files fixed the problem for these users. As you said, it's difficult to find much else about it.

Comment: Definitely don't have a tablet installed. I have a pair of USB headphones connected to my computer, I wonder if that's the culprit.

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine... I think the best advice I saw in that regard was "try changing windows audio settings". Not much to go on, I know, but "audio-related" is the one relatively steady theme I've come across. I guess all you can do is tinker with it.

Comment: For sure, thanks for trying to help and the additional information.